# MS Teams Bot - Error - Failed to acquire token for client credentials

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created MS Teams bot which sends proactive message to the users. I am using ConnectorClient to send the message. I have implemented Error emails so whenever there is an error I get email with the error details.
Last few days I am getting this error for few users.

**Failed to acquire token for client credentials. (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.)**

Below is the detail error message I am getting.

*Failed to acquire token for client credentials. (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.) (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ThrottleException' was thrown.)
StackTrace: at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.Retry.Run[TResult](Func`1 task, Func`3 retryExceptionHandler) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AdalAuthenticator.GetTokenAsync(Boolean forceRefresh) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AdalAuthenticator.Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.IAuthenticator.GetTokenAsync(Boolean forceRefresh) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.GetTokenAsync(Boolean forceRefresh) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.CreateConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(ConversationParameters parameters, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.CreateConversationAsync(IConversations operations, ConversationParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.WelcomeBotCloundStorage.sendMessage(ConnectorClient connectorClient, UserDetails user, Activity personalMessageActivity)*

Answer (score 1):

Throttling can occur when there are too many requests being made within a specific time frame, exceeding the rate limits set by the Microsoft Bot Framework.

Can implement retry logic: Throttling can be temporary, so implementing a retry mechanism can help handle these situations. You can catch the **ThrottleException** and retry the operation after a brief delay.
Refer link: [Optimize your bot with rate limiting in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit)